# MediaPlayer is null on a single device

Tags: android, audio

I've got an app published in the Play Store which rings in some circunstances. Well, I've got a user who can't use the app because it breaks when it should sound. I'm receiving the error in the Developer site, and it's a nullpointerexception.

It only happens to a single user, it's very strange.

```
private MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
    Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alert == null) {
        alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        if (alert == null) {
            alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        }
    }
    if (alert != null) {
        return MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), alert);
    } else {
        return MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.android_notification);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    player = getMediaPlayer();
}

private void sound() {
if (player == null) {
        player = getMediaPlayer();
    }
    if (!player.isPlaying()) {
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.start();
        totalSound++;
    }
....
}
```

When it arrives to player.isPlaying() always throws a nullpointerexception on a single device, and I don't know why. It's a Samsung Galaxy 7 Edge, Android 7.0.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: use try-catch and see if you can catch any exception.

Comment: Of course I've got an exception, a nullpointerexception. Even if I change and write: if (player != null && !player.isPlaying()) {... this lines throws a nullpointerexception.